# navigation drawer with tabs inside

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, drawer, userinfo

I would like to do a Navigation Drawer with a user info, Photo and name (like play store)
and a 3 Tabs to switch three Listviews.
(I think it's more easier for user manage three diferent list)

Like this:

[image]

I already read this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top
...and a lot of pages on internet :(

The idea of developer.android.com to make a collapsible navigation items, it's good, but i think in my case three tabs it's more comfortable and legible...

I thought place a RelativeLayout instead a ListView, but don't be fooled, i'm so newbie on android (and english language too, sorry), so I don't get how to code this... my MainActivity it's a ViewPager... should i use another ViewPager inside the DrawerLayout to get my three tabs?

...some structure of how the code should be much help!!!

If I'm asking too much... mmm... some links on internet maybe? :P

Thanks in advance!  :)

P.D.: If I'm doing something wrong in this comunity... please tell me!!!  =o

Comment: "but i think in my case three tabs it's more comfortable and legible" -- IMHO, only on perhaps a 10" tablet. Your navigation drawer on a phone should not be wider than a fingertip or two, making tabs unsuitable. "i'm so newbie on android" -- I would recommend that you start with a simpler GUI design, one that better fits existing documentation, style guides, and samples. Eventually, you may be in position to do a complex design like the one that you propose, but IMHO you need to "learn to walk before you learn to run".

Comment: You're right!!!  i'm running before time... in fact... i was testing some Drawers and i realize that it's more natural behavior or/and easy, the up and down movement when you use so many options so many times. With tab visually looks more orderly but... as you say... and i see it's true... it's not enough space!
Thanks for that!!! :)
and for "IMHO" expression... i didn't know it! :D  (i speak spanish)

Comment: Thanks for revision vape!, how can I set a CommonsWare's comment like an answer? :)